# SCSS partials (@import) vs. Webpack file import?

Tags: webpack, sass

I'm building a simple app and am setting up my own Webpack configuration to better understand how it works. Currently, I have one `main.scss` file (where I'm writing all my styles) which I'm importing into my `index.js` file (which is the entry point I've set for Webpack). So far, so good.

Now I want to split my SCSS into separate, smaller files (normalize, variables, mixins, etc.) Before Webpack, what I'd do was make every file a SCSS partial and then import all of them into my `main.scss` file. But now that I'm using Webpack, I'm wondering if I should keep doing that or if I should import all of my SCSS files into Webpack instead and forgo partials entirely? Any clarification on the topic would be useful; I haven't found much online about the advantages of one approach over the other.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a setup I've used in past React projects:

- import `main.scss` from your `index.js`
- In your `main.scss` use [`import-glob-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader) to automate the process of importing new sass files -- it's easy to forget to add every new sass file to `main.scss`. Your `main.scss` would look something like:

**main.scss**

```
@import "src/normalize"
@import "src/components/**/*"
```

**Webpack.config.js** (Webpack 2+)

```
 rules: [
    {
        test: /\.scss/,
        enforce: "pre",
        loader: "import-glob-loader"
    },
    // ... other loaders
]
```

This will automatically bundle new sass files that you add to `src`. When using this setup it's important to minimize `@import`s in your sass files as this will increase the overall size of the generated CSS file. The exception is `@import`ing files that only contain mixins and variables, as these imports do not add to the file size.

This setup makes the most sense when used with a framework like React, where you would have many sass files in many different directories (usually in the respective component's directory)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this situation in a small multi page application I was building. When I got to the point where I started splitting the css based on pages, let's say `page-1.scss`, `page-2.scss`, and `page-3.scss`, I wanted to create a `common.bundle.css` which contained css used on all pages.

At first, I had an `@import '_base';` declaration at the top of each `page-*.scss` file. I assumed `CommonsChunkPlugin` would take into account these similar imports and extract them into `common.bundle.css`. But I found that `_base.scss` was still duplicated across each `page-*.bundle.css`. After importing each shared partial in the page's respective entry js file, `CommonsChunkPlugin` was able to correctly extract each shared partial into `common.bundle.css`.

It seemed as though using the SCSS `@import` imported all partials into one css file and then webpack treated that file as one dependency. Using webpack's `import` treated each partial as a dependency which `CommonsChunkPlugin` was able to act on.

So, for my one situation, importing through webpack was preferable to SCSS imports. Unfortunately, I do not have any relevant links on this particular situation, as this is all based on personal experience.